# SQL Value is being replaced by the next value in table

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Im doing this check between my Test enviroment and my prod environment.
Im using a table and sending that table by email to myself with the data missing from test or prod(Data that isnt matching).

```
SET @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @tableHTML = N'<H3> Rows </H3>'+
N'<table border = "1">'+
N'<tr><th>ID</th>'+
N'<th>Company</th>'+
N'<th>Text</th>'+
N'<th>Land</th>'+

CAST ((SELECT td=ID,'',
td = Company, '',
td = [Text],'',
td = Land, ''

FROM (SELECT ID, Company, [Text], Land
FROM (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Test] 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Prod]) data
GROUP BY
ID, Company, [Text], Land
HAVING COUNT(*)!=2) T

for XML Path ('tr'), TYPE) as NVARCHAR(MAX))+
N'</table>';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'My Email;',
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML';
```

**Problem:**

So the problem is i got this procedure and it send me an email. But lets say the Text field in the database is empty. It wont be empty in the table it will be replace by the next value found which will be Land value.

Any1 got any idea how to solve this? I want the text value in the table to be '' (Empty string) or NULL instead of being replaced by the value of Land. And the land value will be missing.

**EDIT:** The XML Output is looking good but when it is parsed to the Html table there is problem. All columns which is null from top to bottom is being replaced by the next column with a value on any row.

Comment: What SQL Server version were you using? The answers would change depending on the SQL Server version.

Comment: Im using Sql Server 2012 with verision 11.0.5058.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by using

```
for XML path ('tr'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL
) as NVARCHAR(MAX))+
```

for xml doesnt handle nulls as default if not specified with xsinil. Which means it set xsi:nil ="true"